# Is there a native way to convert .aac to .mp3 (audio format conversion)

Tags: powershell

I currently use vlc from the command line (called from powershell) to convert .aac to .mp3.

It works, but I don't love the dependence on vlc. Further, the vlc command line is a bear. I worked it out, but I am concerned it will be a real hassle to maintain over time.

I see that ffmpeg is a much simpler tool to use than vlc for this purpose. However I still don't love the dependency.

Is there a Powershell or .NET (callable from powershell) native way to do this?

Or a plugin for Powershell that handles this?

Comment: Why not just make a function?

Comment: There [is a way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/about-the-audio-compression-manager), but it'll involve writing a lot of complicated code to interact with a number of legacy APIs in Windows. vlc (or ffmpeg) cli is going to feel like a breeze in comparison :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks! Yeah, I see what you mean. A ton of old win32 calls... there appear to be a couple of C# wrappers (yeti, and one or two others?) but that is also a mess from a powershell perspective...  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @jonesomeReinstateMonica Have you tried Audacity?

Comment: @DSSO21  does audacity work from the command line?

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica Yes it can https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe AudioWorks is something for you? Check out here [hydrogenaudio - AudioWorks](https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=AudioWorks)

"AudioWorks is a PowerShell module (and .NET library) for converting and tagging audio / music files"

On github [here](https://github.com/jherby2k/AudioWorks).

However note that it lacks native .aac file support. For that, it requires iTunes to be on the system, which may not be an improvement over needing VLC.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I enhanced your post a tad.  And THANK YOU! That is basically what I am looking for!

Comment: Turns out AudioWorks  is not a solve. To get aac file support requires installing iTunes, which is a ton of overhead and dependency that is out of scope for my project. Still looking for a path forward!